# CAShapeLayer resulting in no image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, cashapelayer

I'm trying to make uiimageview top corners rounded but when CASharpeLayer is drawn image gets disappear, i don't know what causing this issue i've put below code in willDisplayCell. when cell is reused images appears properly with drawn layer

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.imgProduct.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0,3.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = cell.imgProduct.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
cell.imgProduct.layer.mask = maskLayer;
cell.imgProduct.layer.masksToBounds=NO;
```

Comment: Why don't put this code into cell subclass's `layoutSubView` ?

Comment: the same issue in layoutSubView too

Comment: well i'm using xcode 8.0 beta is it a problem with that?

Comment: Why you put this code in `willDisplayCell`, you should keep this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: don't you think this may lead to performance issues @MehulThakkar if we put this in cellForItemAtIndexPath ? I've read many tutorials they says we should not make heavy operations in cellForItemAtIndexPath/cellForRowAtIndexPath which may cause choppy scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by myself...:P i've drawn the mask in drawRect method of my UICollectionViewCell subclass

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.imgProduct.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = self.imgProduct.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    _imgProduct.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    _imgProduct.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

}
```